# 'extra charge' or 'extra paid' - what is correct?

Tags: conditionals

Is that sentence correct:

The situation in a restaurant, answer to a waiter:

> If you had told me the appetizer was extra charge / extra paid, I would have given you a tip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just say "extra" without "paid" or "charge".  "Cost extra" would sound more correct than "was extra".

If you really wanted to use one, you could say "an extra charge".

Comment: If you had told me the appetizer cost extra, I would have given you a tip. - OK?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

"extra Charge", "extra cost" and "extra paid/payment" or "additional payment" are the substitutes of each other. so the statement is correct.